# Fast multi-body gravity algorithm?

Tags: java, optimization, simulation, gravity

I am writing a program to simulate an n-body gravity system, whose precision is arbitrarily good depending on how small a step of "time" I take between each step. Right now, it runs very quickly for up to 500 bodies, but after that it gets very slow since it has to run through an algorithm determining the force applied between each pair of bodies for every iteration. This is of complexity n(n+1)/2 = O(n^2), so it's not surprising that it gets very bad very quickly. I guess the most costly operation is that I determine the distance between each pair by taking a square root. So, in pseudo code, this is how my algorithm currently runs:

```
for (i = 1 to number of bodies - 1) {
  for (j = i to number of bodies) {
   (determining the force between the two objects i and j,
    whose most costly operation is a square root)
  }
}
```

So, is there any way I can optimize this? Any fancy algorithms to reuse the distances used in past iterations with fast modification? Are there any lossy ways to reduce this problem? Perhaps by ignoring the relationships between objects whose x or y coordinates (it's in 2 dimensions) exceed a certain amount, as determined by the product of their masses? Sorry if it sounds like I'm rambling, but is there anything I could do to make this faster? I would prefer to keep it arbitrarily precise, but if there are solutions that can reduce the complexity of this problem at the cost of a bit of precision, I'd be interested to hear it.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I'm being dense, but don't you get the distance with sqrt(x^2 + y^2) and then immediately square it in G*m1*m2/r^2 to get the force? Couldn't you take out the square root altogether?

Comment: @JamesMoughan That doesn't work. Because you don't want to calculate the absolute value of the force, but the force vector. And in this formula you get `r_vec/Abs(r)^3`

Comment: But the main issue here isn't the cost of the square-root. It's that the algorithm is quadratic in the number of objects. Using approximations that group objects together you can cut that down to `n*log(n)` or something similar.

Comment: you can remove the square root all together just as james said.
I just tested it out both ways with identical results.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/19393/optimizing-gravity-calculations). You can divide your objects into a grid, and use the fact that many faraway objects can be treated as a single object for a good approximation. The mass of a cell is equal to the sum of the masses of the objects it contains. The centre of mass of a cell can be treated as the centre of the cell itself, or more accurately the [barycenter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass) of the objects it contains. In the average case, I think this gives you O(*n* log *n*) performance, rather than O(*n*<sup>2</sup>), because you still need to calculate the force of gravity on each of *n* objects, but each object only interacts *individually* with those nearby.

Assuming you’re calculating the distance with *r*<sup>2</sup> = *x*<sup>2</sup> + *y*<sup>2</sup>, and then calculating the force with *F* = G*m*<sub>1</sub>*m*<sub>2</sub> / *r*<sup>2</sup>, you don’t need to perform a square root at all. If you do need the actual distance, you can use a [fast inverse square root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root). You could also used [fixed-point arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic).

Comment: Not sure how you want to avoid the square-root.

Comment: Also I don't recommend fixed points. They're annoying to work with, and I don't expect a significant performance gain. I'd rather look into vector instructions from SSE which work on several floats at one.

Comment: @CodesInChaos This is just basic maths. If you've got a `(√x)²`, that's just equal to `x` and thus you can avoid using both the `sqrt` and the `pow` functions a few times. 

So to simplify the algorithm, you should use the last formula:
`F = Gm1m2/r²`
`F = Gm1m2/√[(x1-x2)²+(y1-y2)]²`
`F = Gm1m2/[(x1-x2)²+(y1-y2)]`

Comment: @Beyondo You're calculating the magnitude of the force, but the OP needs the force-*vector* for their simulation. I see no way to calculate the vector without a sqrt operation (or the even more expensive `pow(r², 1.5)`).

Comment: @CodesInChaos To get the vector force, you just multiply that magnitude of the force that we got by the normalized direction which is just the difference between the two objects' positions divided by their length (which is the only thing that uses sqrt). I never said you are skipping the usage of sqrt, I rather said "avoid using them a few times" so you are just minimizing their usage like when you calculated the force magnitude, not eliminating their need which is what the OP meant.

Comment: The post said "you don’t need to perform a square root at all", my comment points out that you can't avoid having at least one square-root calculation to get the force-vector required for the simulation. I'd write the code as `r_squared = r_vec.magnitude_squared(); F_vec = r_vec * (Gm1m2 / (r_squared * sqrt(r_squared))` to minimize expensive operations without relying on fast-math optimizations.

Comment: @CodesInChaos He said we don't need to perform a `sqrt` at all **in that formula:** `F = Gm1m2 / r²` by which he quoted it before he said that sentence, however, I gotta cut you some slack on that one that it might cause misunderstandings! It's all good mate; we're on the same page. If we wanted a real optimization for Nbody, we'd probably use an entire different algorithm like Barnes–Hut or so unless we need 100% classical accuracy.

Answer (score 3):

One good lossy approach would be to run a [clustering algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) to cluster the bodies together.

There are [some](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_clustering#Fuzzy_c-means_clustering) clustering algorithms that are fairly fast, and the trick will be to not run the clustering algorithm every tick. Instead run it every C ticks (C>1).

Then for each cluster, calculate the forces between all bodies in the cluster, and then for each cluster calculate the forces between the clusters.

This will be lossy but I think it is a good approach.

You'll have to fiddle with:

- which clustering algorithm to use: Some are faster, some are more accurate. Some are deterministic, some are not.
- how often to run the clustering algorithm: running it less will be faster, running it more will be more accurate.
- how small/large to make the clusters: most clustering algorithms allow you some input on the size of the clusters. The larger you allow the clusters to be, the faster but less accurate the output will be.

So it's going to be a game of speed vs accuracy, but at least this way you will be *able* to sacrafice a bit of accuracy for some speed gains - with your current approach there's nothing you can really tweak at all.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try a less precise version of square root. You probably don't need a full double precision. Especially if the order of magnitude of your coordinate system is normally the same, then you can use a truncated taylor series to estimate the square root operation pretty quickly without giving up too much in efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good approximation to the n-body problem that is much faster (O(n log n) vs O(n²) for the naive algorithm) called [Barnes Hut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes%E2%80%93Hut_simulation). Space is subdivided into a hierarchical grid, and when computing force contribution for distant masses, several masses can be considered as one. There is an accuracy parameter that can be tweaked depending on how much your willing to sacrifice accuracy for computation speed.